# Executable file to change directory macosx terminal not working

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, sh

1. Created the file with nano editor
2. Gave executable permissions to all users with:
   `chmod +x [filename]`
3. execute the following command in terminal :
   `./filename`

The problem is that the file runs but doesn't change the directory to Desktop

System: Macosx Monterey

Content of the file

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Desktop
```

Comment: `source` the script. e.g. `source ./filemane` or `. ./filename`  see [link](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/060)

Comment: When you execute a script, that script is run in a new instance of the shell.  So the instant it completes, it is gone, and your `cd` does not mean anything to the calling shell.  In order to affect the shell you are in, you have to use source instead of executing the script, like @Jetchisel commented above.

Comment: Thank you Jetchisel and Nic3500 It's that! So simple :)